# Make card game GUI in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to write code for a card game in Java.
I've already written all necessary classes to run the game, and I can already play the game in the console.

Now I want to create a GUI around this to make interaction easier. To give a bit of context, these are my classes:

- `Card` (contains rank / suit)
- `CardList` (extends `ArrayList<Card>`)
- `Deck`, `Pile`, `Hand` (extends `CardList`)
- `Player` (contains a `Hand`, and a `CardList` indicating the cards the player has played)
- `Game` (contains a `List<Player>`, a `Deck`, a `Pile` and info about the current game position)

Now I've already been fiddling around a bit, and I've made an inner class `CardListPanel` in `CardList` extending `JPanel`, that in its turn will be filled with several instances of `CardPanel`, that is an inner class of `Card`, exteding `JPanel` as well.

For the `CardPanel` I've written a `paintComponent()` that draws the card (if necessary rotated by `r` degrees), and when initialising `CardListPanel`, I calculate the desired positions of the cards, and their rotations, such that they appear in some form of arc, as displayed below:

[image]

Now I'm wondering if the idea I described above is good practice to write a GUI for a card game, to make sort of nested JPanels, and paint the card as a part of CardList-panels. Or, would it be better to draw all cards onto a JFrame separately, to be able to move them around more easily. Or, yet another possibility, am I missing the entire concept of JFrames / JPanels (to which I'm new), am I misusing them, and is there some established practice to make these sorts of GUI's?

Comment: Keep model (logical code) separate from view (GUI code). There should likely be one main drawing JPanel that has its paintComponent overridden.

Comment: So I could better move the inner Panel-classes out of the `Card` and `CardList` classes?

Comment: Based on the complexity of the UI you're trying to produce, I'm thinking a single component to render all the cards is a better choice, the mouse management would be simpler, the z-ordering would easier, the management and functionality would be easier to maintain overall